# hibernate how to map a column substring to the attribute of a bean class

Tags: hibernate, substring, javabeans

In Hibernate, I would like to know if it is possible to map an attribute of a bean class to a column in a SQL table to get only a part of the column content (a substring).

For example, if I have an attribute ShortArticle mapped to column Article, and I want ShortArticle to take the first 100 characters of this column only, how can I do this?

It would be like mapping the bean attribute to a SQL query:

CASE
WHEN len(ar.Article)>100 THEN SUBSTRING(ar.Article,0,100) + '...'
ELSE SUBSTRING(ar.Article,0,100)

is there any way to do this in Hibernate?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I changed my approach: rather than mapping the bean directly to the table, I created a view displaying the information I need and linked the bean to the view